# Error while running omnet++ after implementing a new physical propagation model

Tags: veins

I added new `.cc` and header files describing a new propagation and fading model on the `analoguemodel` folder. I also made the changes to `PhyLayer80211p` files. 
I run `"make -j 4 MODE=release"` and it executes without problems.
When I try to run veins on the `omnet++` gui the follow error comes up:

> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.so': ../../src//libveins.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN5Veins16HighwayPropModelE.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new .cc file (or removing one) you need to re-run the `configure` script, so the command line build process knows to include/exclude it.